# Vinyl floating floor help

Tags: flooring

This is odd, but needed.
My problem is floating vinyl planks was put on unlevel subfloor. Planks moved when walking.

I learned floating is suppose to move some, expand etc.

Problem is I get dizzy. Medically. I NEVER should have done floating.

The floor is now level. But I want to add some vinyl tape to it as its installed.

I know its not designed to be. I don’t care or have a choice.

The guys now want 1,000 bucks to add tape. They do strips every 6 inches.

If I ask them to do every 3ft so that each plank has one strip of tape, is that enough to secure it?

It might save labor cost. And if it is strong enough at that width can it work?
thank you

Comment: Floating floors or most hard material floors want and need a flat floor.  A flat floor is a floor were a long straight edge lies flat on the the floor.  A slope/not level is different.  Tape will not help much is the floor is flat or not.  Making sure the floor is flat is what will help.  I put a floating floor down on a flat floor.  There is no floor movement.  They are charging that much because it should be a waste of their time.

Comment: First, a floating floor doesn't move much because of its weight.  Second, the movement is minimal given there is only a tiny gap on the perimeter.  Third, unless your floor is heavily inclined, it should not cause the floor not move.  Before you pay for putting the tapes, I would recommend finding the real root cause of your dizziness.

Comment: Another reason for movement when walking on a floor is a weaker sub floor.  If the sub floor is not stiff enough, walking can cause it to bend/move up and down.  Tile requires plus inch thick sub floor so there is no movement.  You probably want at least 3/4 inch sub floor for stiffness/very tiny movement.  This depends if the floor joists are the right size.

Comment: That is a misnomer. The floors do not move as you walk on it. They might expand (very slowly) due to the temperature. Tape is not needed.

Comment: LVP needs a little time to "relax" .  It is possible that the floor moves ( Dips in small divots.) an almost imperceptible amount.  The minor movement that one may get when stepping in certain areas goes away in short time.

Comment: if you do successfully secure each plank, you can expect the floor to buckle or un-snap when the temp/humidity changes with the seasons.

Comment: @dandavis, LVP does not react to temps or humidity changes like that.  It does not even need to be acclimated.

Comment: @RMDman exactly, the wood it's attached to changes, so if the planks don't and are stuck, bad things happen.